# How do I return errors back from module to main script in powershell?

Tags: powershell, exception, logging

I have created a PowerShell module `SearchGoogle.psm1`:

```
function SearchGoogle($queryString) {
    try {
        $searchURL = "http://www.google.co.uk?q={0}" -f $queryString
        $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $searchURL
        return $WebResponse
    }
    catch {
        $error = "ERROR: Unable to get URL: $searchURL"
        return $error
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this from my main script `main.ps1` like the following:

```
Import-Module .\SearchGoogle.psm1
$result = SearchGoogle "hello world"

if($result -like "ERROR:*") {
    #log error

    # do not progress program any further
    Exit
}
```

This works fine and I can control the logging in my main program and now in the module. However I'm not sure this is the best way of doing things.

If I use a throw "Error: blah" in my module, I am unable to know what is going on in my main program to make decisions.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Generally, you should use module items as elements in your main script, not the other way around.  If you need to return values it's usually best to return an object, not just an error. e.g. In the module function catch block you could use something like "Return [pscustomobject]@{Error = $true; ErrorMsg = $_} and test for the returned object in your main script.
Without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to guess why you think you have a problem.

Comment: I'm just creating a list of common functions that I can use in my scripts.

Comment: What;s your problem then? Just look at making your functions more robust, using Try..Catch etc.

Comment: I was just wondering how and where throwing exceptions would come in